# Drush installation

Tags: php, drupal, drush

I'm new at drupal development, and I installed module_builder now I try to install Drush I just download this, but don't now how to install it on my windows computer, I have a single website. Couldn't find a good tutorial to install it. have someone experience with Drush and how to install it? thanks!

Comment: Not a programming question, belongs on serverfault.

Comment: I found a good tutorial. http://ninjagirl.com/posts/013/installing-drush-windows

Comment: @MarcB: not a programming question, should go to superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dedicated page with several resources on the official Drupal website :

https://drupal.org/node/594744

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at Acquia Dev Desktop. 
It comes together with drush and is a very easy way to work on windows.

https://www.acquia.com/downloads